# Android async get image

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

I try to decode to bipmap from input stream URL

public class Presenter implements MVPmain.presenter {

```
String LOG_TAG = "Presenter: ";

private final MVPmain.view view;
String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";

public Presenter(MVPmain.view view) {
    this.view = view;
}


void photosUrl() {
        String photoUrl = "http://placehold.it/600/92c952";
        AsyncLoadImage asyncLoadImage = new AsyncLoadImage();
        asyncLoadImage.execute(photoUrl);
    }
}

@Override
public void button_photos_clicked() {
    photosUrl();
}

Bitmap loadImage(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmapImage = null;
    URL imageUrl = null;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    try {
        imageUrl = new URL(url.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", ""));
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
        bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Runneble: " + "OK");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "image url error: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmapImage;
}


class AsyncLoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    String LOG_TAG = "AsyncLoadImage: ";
    Bitmap bitmapImage;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String request = "";
        final URL imageUrl = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        for (final String address : strings) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "img url: " + address);
            bitmapImage = loadImage(address);

        }
        return bitmapImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmapImg) {
            view.setPhotos(bitmapImg);
    }

}
```

}

it's a part of code, where I get exception: Connection refused in httpURLConnection.getInputStream(). I try .getContent and get this error too.
Please, tell me, how I can do this.

**SOLVED**
This error cases AdWay!)

Comment: did you add   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in Manifest

Comment: Yes. At first I get the address of the photo from here: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/3, asynctask work with this url, but not work with image url: http://placehold.it/600/92c952.
For example this url: https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly in my device.

Make sure your internet connection is working properly and also open the image URL directly from the browser in your android device to verify that you have access to the URL.

Comment: From chrome on mobile I can open this image. But from my app no. Screenshot of error: 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vwlK.png

Comment: test in other devices. it might be device specific problem.

Comment: you right! On a virtual device code is work... I try before on my nexus 5 7.1.2